# All cells like strings PHP Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I'm trying to read some data from excel file. Everything is good if i have ex.50.44% in my excel cell PHP excel format it like float 0.0531 i dont want to format any numbers and i want all cell to be casted as string. How can i accomplish this before making the data toArray();

Here my sample code

```
try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($upload_url);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($upload_url,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

 $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
->getNumberFormat()
->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);


$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
var_dump($sheetData);
exit;
```

[image]
Any help will be appreacited.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want all values as strings rather than the appropriate datatype, then retrieve your array as you're doing at the moment, then execute:

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $sheetData,
    function (&$value) {
        $value = (string) $value;
    }
);
```

Comment: The values are already formated and broken.
 'O' => string '0.1096' (length=6)
      'P' => string '0.2955' (length=6)
      'Q' => string '0.3065' (length=6)
      'R' => string '0.3198' (length=6)

The original values is 50.44% and in the array is 0.531

Comment: Remove `$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
->getNumberFormat()
->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);` because this will break formatting. Otherwise, are you doing anything else that might be disabling formatting? (e.g. setting `loadDataOnly(true)` or similar?

Comment: I want to disable formatting. I dont want PHP excel to format my cell values. In my cell in .xls file value i have 50.44% and PHP excel format to 0.05311. I also tried without $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle() ->getNumberFormat() ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);

Comment: The value stored in MS Excel is `0.05311`.... MS Excel uses a "number format mask" to display that value as `50.44%`.... PHPExcel does exactly the same, unless you change the mask..... so don't try to override that mask by setting your own format code.... if you disable formatting", or change the formatting mask, then you'll never get `50.44%`

Comment: So how can i get the original value ?

Comment: The original value is `0.05044`. the formatted value is `50.44%`.... use `toArray()` with `true` as the third argument to get PHPExcel to return the formatted value, `false` if you want the original/raw value..... but don't change any formatting codes yourself